# I want the object created to be accessed in the domain afterInsert is done

Tags: grails, dns

how do acces the current object created in the afterInsert trigger of the domain?

eg.
I want to keep the id of object created in some other domain after the object is created

I have a domain order whose status is going to change a various number of time.
I want this changes to be recorded in other domain order history.

in order domain I wrote hasMany[orderHistory:orderHistory]
in the orderHistory domain i wrote belongsTo = [order:order]

But the orderHistory is coming common to all ie. each order is not having just their record but recoreds of all orders are being shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the id of the created instance just use `this.id`.

```
def afterInsert = {
    log.debug "ID of currently created instance: ${this.id}"
}
```